# ¿Como conectar a un middleware en java para hacer POST,GET y PUT con JSON?

Tags: java, json

me piden hacer POST,GET y PUT con un JSON a un servidor middleware, me dieron una URL para poder hacer mi conexión y mandar un JSON para después hacer el respectivo GET yPUT ,el POST, GET y PUT tienen una dirección cada uno Por ejemplo: POST /Net/Persona

El problema es que no tengo ni idea de como hacer esto, no busco que me pongan todo el código solo quiero saber por donde debo empezar a buscar o que puedo hacer para hacerlo.

Hasta ahorita he visto que se tiene que hacer con maven y jersey, pero no se si esto realmente va a funcionar o no.

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) herramienta muy util para probar apis

Comment: Necesitas una librería que haga llamadas sobre HTTP(S), algo como la clase RestTemplate de Spring Framework o HttpComponents de Apache

Comment: Lee sobre servicios web RESTFul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplos de consumo de Web Service RESTful en java:

```
public void listarJson(){
        String urlstr="http://url/restful/empleados/json/listarempleados";
        try{
            URL url = new  URL(urlstr);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            JsonReader rdr=Json.createReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            JsonArray results= rdr.readArray();
            Iterator<?> iterator = results.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("JSON-> El id es: "+jsonObject.get("id").toString().toUpperCase()+", el nombre es: "+jsonObject.get("nombre").toString().toUpperCase()+", el puesto es: "+jsonObject.get("puesto").toString().toUpperCase());
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void insertar(){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo Id: ");
            String id = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo nombre: ");
            String nombre = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nuevo puesto: ");
            String puesto = br.readLine();
            String url="http://url/restful/empleados/insertar/"+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8")+"/"+URLEncoder.encode(nombre,"UTF-8")+"/"+URLEncoder.encode(puesto,"UTF-8");
            URL urlObj=new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conexion=(HttpURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();
            conexion.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            conexion.connect();
            System.out.println(conexion.getResponseMessage());
            conexion.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void borrar(){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el id a borrar: ");
            String id = br.readLine();
            String url="http://url/restful/empleados/borrar/"+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8");
            URL urlObj=new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conexion=(HttpURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();
            conexion.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
            conexion.connect();
            System.out.println(conexion.getResponseMessage());
            conexion.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta, revisar [answer]

Comment: No responde a la pregunta? y entonces porque fue aceptada